# How to build two dimensional arrays from a query?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have a query in Rails that's extracting 3 data points: data1, data2, and datetime.  I need to assemble these into two different 2D arrays for insertion into a graph (Highcharts) such as this: http://jsfiddle.net/RKVgx/

You can see that the data will ultimately be used in the js like:

```
series: [{
    data: [[6, 540], [7, 540], [7, 1620], [8, 1620]]
},{
    data: [[6, 340], [7, 340], [7, 620], [8, 620]]
}]
```

By using [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) this is pretty straight forward, however I simply need to compose the arrays appropriately for output.  What I was thinking was something like this, but I need some help in building the 2D arrays properly for insertion:

```
readings = ModelName.order("date DESC").select('table_name.data1, table_name.data2, table_name.date').limit(1000).all

# HELP HERE, Need 2D arrays here...
data2_and_time_array = Array.new
data1_and_time_array = Array.new

readings.each do |row|
  # HELP HERE, build place datetime into each for X axis
  data1_and_time_array.push row[:date]
  data2_and_time_array.push row[:date]

  # These are the Y data points in each series
  data1_and_time_array.push row[:data2].to_f
  data2_and_time_array.push row[:data1].to_f

end


f.series(
    :name => 'Data1',
    # Date is X & must be first in each 2D array, I believe
    # in format of: [[X1, Y1], [X2, Y2], ... [Xn, Yn]]
    :data => data1_and_time_array 
)
f.series(
    :name => 'Data2',
    :data => data2_and_time_array
)
```

If you could provide the appropriate fixes / logic to do this correctly in the example code above, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: too many details in the input data. Simply give an example input (Ruby object) without further ado, and the output you want (you already did that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i understand well what you want, but [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) should do the trick :

```
data2_and_time_array = readings.map{|row| [row.date, row.data1.to_f] }
data1_and_time_array = readings.map{|row| [row.date, row.data2.to_f] }
```

**EDIT :**

you can perform any processing you want inside the block :

```
data2_and_time_array = readings.map do{|row| [row.date, row.data1 == -1 ? row.data1.to_f : nil] }
```

when performing complex processing, it is encouraged to use the `do...end` block syntax for a more readable code :

```
data2_and_time_array = readings.map do |row| 
  date, data = row.date, row.data1
  data = (data == -1) ? nil : data.to_f
  [date, data]
end
```

Comment: In addition to this, if a certain value of `row.data1 == -1` then it should push a nil onto the stack, can you do that also simply in the shorter block you used?  I'm assuming it will move into a multiline do block at this point.

Comment: Ended up using a variant on that: `data1_and_date_array = readings.map{|row| [row.date, (row.short.to_f if BigDecimal(row.data1) != BigDecimal("-100.0"))] }`